# Al editar las reglas de seguridad en Firebase me sale parse error y no puedo publicar los cambios

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin

**estoy poniendo este codigo en el editor de reglas de firebase pero me sale parse error**

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 7, 14);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error específicamente?